# writing lines to a txt file python

Tags: python-3.x, format, lines

I have a txt file with IDs and 34 numerical values for each ID. These represent individual labels and 17 coordinates (x,y) indicating geometric landmarks on a digital photo for each ID.

The input is a txt file in this format:
ID1 x1 y1
ID1 x2 y2
ID1 x3 y3
ID1 x4 y4
.....
ID1 x17 y17
ID2 x1 y1
ID2 x2 y2
.....
ID2 x17 y17
and so on....

I need the output file to be like this:
ID1 x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4........x17 y17
ID2 x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3...........x17 y17

I simply put the columns of the input file into lists so I have a list of IDs (str), a list of xs (str) and a list of ys (str).

```
for i in range(0, len(x), 17):
    coord = '\t'.join([x[i+j] + '\t' + y[i+j] for j in range(16)])
    OutputFile.write(ID[i] + "\t" + coord)
```

However, my output txt file looks like this:
ID1 x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
x4 y4
ID2 x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
x4 y4

So, how can I write all coordinates on the same line? I'm using Python 3.4.0 and all my data are str types.

Thanks

Comment: not clear what you trying to achive

Comment: I re-edited the question, hopefully is clearear now :)

Comment: can you post a simple input and it's output? it'll be very helpful since most of us probably did similar things already :)

Comment: I'd love to, but how can I add txt files as examples in the question? I can't add photos yet

Comment: I re-re-edited the question to make it clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply can't reproduce your results on Python 3.3. Note that your string addition won't work if the values in x, y are integers so do make sure that they're not `\n`-terminated strings. For example, the following is closest to your code and seems to do what you want:

```
n, nf = 2, 4
x = [str(i) for i in range(n * nf)]
y = [str(i*2) for i in range(n * nf)]
ID = [str(10*i) for i in range(nf)]
OutputFile = open('output2.txt', 'w')
nx = len(x)
for i in range(0, len(x), nf):
    OutputFile.write(ID[i//nf] + "\t" + x[i] + "\t" + y[i] + "\t" +  x[i+1] + "\t" + y[i+1] + "\t" + x[i+2] + "\t" + y[i+2] + "\t" + x[i+3] + "\t" + y[i+3] + "\n")
OutputFile.close()
```

and the more Pythonic:

```
n, nf = 2, 4
x = [str(i) for i in range(n * nf)]
y = [str(i*2) for i in range(n * nf)]
ID = [str(1001*i) for i in range(nf)]
OutputFile = open('output3.txt', 'w')
for i in range(0, len(x), nf):
    line = '\t'.join([x[i+j] + '\t' + y[i+j] for j in range(nf)])
    OutputFile.write(ID[i//nf] + '\t' + line + '\n')
OutputFile.close()
```

also works. You might have to share some of your data to make more progress on this.

Comment: My numerical values are str types. Still can't get it as I want though. I'm really trying to post my data but the editor does not allow me to write them in!

Comment: YES! Did it! It wasn't working beacuse my y was a list of \n -terminated strings! \m/

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're looking for:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as fi:
        for i, line in enumerate(fi.readlines()):
            print(line.strip(), end=' ', file=fo)
            if not (i+1) % 17:
                print(file=fo)
```

It just outputs the lines without line endings, but then does add a line ending to every 17th line. You get a trailing space at the end of every line. If you really don't want this, you could make a list of your input lines and then rejoin them:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as fi:
        lines = []
        for i, line in enumerate(fi.readlines()):
            lines.append(line.strip())
            if not (i+1) % 17:
                print(' '.join(lines))
                lines = []
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is not what I'm looking for. Not sure what the first script actually does, while the second script simply returns my input file as it is. I think my question is simpler than this. My script does what I need apart from the fact that the output doesn't look like what I need. I'd only like to know why it doesn't write on the same line. In python 2.7.x this worked for me.

Comment: Ah. Are you sure that there aren't line endings at the end of your y values (are they read in as strings?)?

Comment: it doesn't matter if I read them in as str or int, the result is always the same. I can't manage to write them on the same line! Damn!

Comment: I can't understand what's wrong with my output.write statement. Why is not writing the elements on the same line?